# Light load efficiency of DC-DC Switching converters

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I have been working with DC-DC Converters theoretically.

What is it that I don't understand is that how the efficiency is very less at light loads? How does the switching and the output get affected?

Light load means that the IC output has the stable output voltage but Load Current is less?

Can someone help me understand the light load behaviour of DC-DC converters in simple terms?

Comment: Switching regulators have a high surge starting current unless soft start active design is included in the IC.  Then the impedance of the switching L at some f for steady state with the DCR and Ron losses determine the idle current losses such that at no load you have 0% efficiency.  There are many choices here but dynamic range may a limiting factor but there are thousands of IC designs to choose from.

Comment: Sorry for the basic question. No load means, We have the Output voltage available at the IC output end, but  zero load current, right?

Comment: Can you explain what you said in a brief manner? I am not able to get clarity. please

Comment: From the switched inductor, dynamic Impedance Z depends on time interval which can be derived from Z = V / dI = L / dt + DCR * I = dZ(t) in the short term and V/I= ω L /I  but dynamic losses come from  transition time/cycle time * I²(R+DCR+ESR) =Pd as a rough estimate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is it that I don't understand is that how the efficiency is very
>   less at light loads?

It's like a car sat at traffic lights - you are not moving hence the fuel consumption in miles per gallon are zero or, power out over power in is zero or, zero efficiency.

A DC/DC converter always wastes a few milliwatts of power in just doing nothing except providing a fixed voltage at the output. If there is no current supplied to a load then the power output is zero and the power efficiency has to be zero.

> How does the switching and the output get affected?

To minimize power losses, some switching converters enter a special mode known as burst mode and the output switching is very infrequent leading to reduced power losses. The (near) equivalent for a car sat at traffic lights is turning the engine off then restarting the engine as the lights turn green.

Comment: thank you for the answer and an understandable analogy. i got clarity now. thank  you

Comment: @Newbie Note that with a shorted load, the efficiency is also (close to) 0% as the output voltage is (close to) 0V.

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Theory/Shorted_Resistors. I read this link when you mentioned shorted load condition. During shorted load, as per the mentioned circuit in that link, current will be very large right. But why is the output voltage=0V?

Comment: When something is shorted out, no matter what current flows, the short is a very low value of resistance hence, the voltage of the "short" is close to 0 volts.

Comment: @Andyaka Thank you very mych for the answer. Accepted your answer. Since my native language is not english and an amateur in electronics field, I accept answer which help me to get some clarity. It was not done intentionally. Sorry.

Comment: You might want to withdraw what you said at the bottom of the other answer. You can delete comments.

Answer (score 3):

The lower efficiency at low output currents is easily explained if you consider that the DCDC converter also consumes some quiescent current. This is the current which the converter needs to operate.

Let's look at an example.

Suppose I have a DCDC converter which consumes 100uA when operating.

So even when \$I_{load}\$ = 0 A, \$I_{in}\$ = 100 uA

Now suppose we apply \$V_{in}\$ = 10 V and configure the converter to output: \$V_{out}\$ = 5 V

No we load the converter with an \$I_{load}\$ = 100 mA, this then means that \$I_{in}\$ =  50 mA + 100 uA = 50.1 mA

That's an efficiency of \$P_{out} / P_{in}\$ = (5 V * 100 mA) / ( 10 V * 50.1 mA) = **99.8 %**

That's a very high efficiency! I'm assuming that the quiescent current of 100 uA does not change for small or large load currents, that isn't a realistic assumption but easier for this explanation.

Now let's do the same calculation bit for \$I_{load}\$ = 100 uA, so a **very light load**:

\$I_{in}\$ will now be:  50 uA + 100 uA = 150 uA

The efficiency will then be \$P_{out} / P_{in}\$ = (5 V * 100 uA) / ( 10 V * 150 uA) = **33.3 %**

That's a lot worse! This is caused by the fact that the load current is not significantly larger than the quiescent current. If the load current was significantly larger than the quiescent current then the quiescent current sort of becomes irrelevant (too small to make a difference).

Answer (score 2):

Light-load efficiency is the hot topic these years. It impacts ac-dc but also dc-dc converters. There are several techniques available to improve efficiency in light-load operations:

1. burst mode or skip cycle: it is the easiest and simplest method to implement. When the load gets lighter, the feedback voltage passes below a certain threshold and the continuous switching pattern is interrupted until the feedback voltage goes back above it. This is a hysteretic behavior and can suffer audible noise issues if the burst occurs at a high peak current: the inductor or the transformer can chime but passive components also sometimes. There are known techniques to limit these effects. Skip cycle usually implies uncontrolled output ripple.
2. Frequency foldback: rather than switching at a continuous 100-kHz frequency (or above) in all conditions, an internal variable signals that output power is getting lower. A voltage-controlled oscillator then regulates the converter by decreasing the operating frequency down to 20-30 kHz so as to remain outside of the audible range. It can happen at a fixed or variable peak current setpoint. Then, if the power still reduces further, the controller enters skip cycle operation. Frequency foldback is nice and efficient. It does not suffer from output ripple as with classical burst mode. It is present on many ac-dc and dc-dc converters.
3. constant on-time: in this mode, the controller drives the off-time duration while the on-time is fixed. At high power, the part switches at high frequencies (small off-time) and then decreases the off-time (switching period expands) when the output power goes down. As a result, it naturally ensures a low switching frequency in light load and efficiency is excellent. Audible noise problems can appear and a minimum frequency limit has to be set. Cool thing, you don't need slope compensation in a true on-time current-mode controller.
4. pure hysteretic: if you use a hysteretic controller like the old and venerable MC34063 - or the µA78S40 from Signetics - but who remembers? :-), then in light-load conditions the switching recurrence is extremely long and efficiency benefits from this mode. The 34063 was known for having audible noise problems but more modern approaches use techniques to compensate the frequency spread.

All switching losses in semiconductors (turn-on and turn-off events, \$Q_{rr}\$ losses in diodes) magnetics losses, they all scale down with frequency. So reducing it naturally lowers the loss budget in the overall efficiency calculation.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer